# EO.WEB dynamically generated JavaScript fails with 404

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ashx

I am using EO.Web dll for my ASP.Net application for progress bar. My app server is load balanced. I also put my script physically in a different folder but after deployment for first few requests I get 404 on the scripts:

scripts/eo_script/eo.7e55b231-d9db-40f6-ad56-84f5b0d0f4b5.js - 404 (not found)

After 3 or 4 loads everything seems to be working fine, but 404s right after deployment is breaking my automated tests.

My guess is that the requests go from one server to another and that's why its 404ing. Is there a way to initialize all the scripts before run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from EO support forum:

There is no way for the code in our component to initialize the files on all servers --- at any given time our code would only be running on one server and files can only be generated on that server. If you need it to work on all servers, you can add these script files into your deployment and deploy them across all servers.The name of the files stays the same for the same version. If you update to a different version of EO.Web.dll, then they will be different.